# PHP Slim and PUT request

Tags: php, http, slim

I'm doing an API and I'm having troubles with PUT method, I have done GET and POST methods without problem but now my problem is that I can't get PUT params and I'm so crazy now.

My code:

```
$app->put(API_ROUTE . '/group/:id', $authenticate($app), function ($id) use ($app) {
 $app->log->addDebug($app->request->getResourceUri(), [$app->request->getMethod()]);
 $em = GetEntityManager();
 $group = $em->getRepository('Api\Entity\Group')->findOneById(mb_convert_encoding($id, 'ISO-8859-1', 'UTF-8'));
 $groupname = $app->request()->params('groupname');
 $description = $app->request()->params('description');
 if($group){
  if(!isset($groupname) || !isset($description)){
    $app->outputData(new HTTP_Status(400, 'Bad request'));
  } else{
   $groupWithSameName = $group = $em->getRepository('Api\Entity\Group')->findOneByGroupname(mb_convert_encoding($groupname, 'ISO-8859-1', 'UTF-8'));
   if($groupWithSameName){
     $app->outputData(new HTTP_Status(400, 'Bad request'));
   }
   else{
    $group->setDescription($description);
    $group->setGroupname($groupname);
    $em->persist($group);
    $em->flush();
    $app->outputData(new HTTP_Status(203, 'Bad request'));
   }
  }
 } else{
    $app->outputData(new HTTP_Status(404, 'Not Found'));
  }
})->conditions(array('id' => '\d+'))
 ->name('put_group');
```

My body petition (Mozilla Dev Edition says it):

```
groupname=aaa&description=aaa
```

And what I get when the petition is done

> **Fatal error**:  Call to a member function setDescription() on
>   null in **E:\Dev\XAMPP\php\API\app\app.php** on line **131**

Line 131 is $group->setDescription(...);

I tried to use

- $app->request->put('description');
- $app->request()->put('description');
- $app->request->params('description');

with same result. I hope you can help me.

Comment: You don't have a variable `$group` in your code. Either you don't have one at all, in which case you won't be able to fall any methods on it, or you need to show where in your code you assign it.

Comment: Please show full code.

Comment: Full code posted, I'm using Doctrine, but I think that's irrelevant. As I said, other methods are working with same style, I'm sorry if I'm in the wrong way

Comment: have you read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23761425/get-put-params-with-slim-php

Comment: Yes, I read it and it doesn't work for me. I have setted data type like example :(

Comment: $app->request->params() or $app->request->put(); when you are making your call make sure your Content-Type is set correctly otherwise Slim doesn't know what to do with your body!

Answer (score 0):

Check, what `$em->getRepository([...])->findOneByGroupname([...])` returns.
Apparently, it is `false` or `null`.

`$group->setDescription()` is ONLY executed if `$groupWithSameName` (and therefor `$group` as well) is null/false.

I could imagine you forgot a `!` in the if statement? `if(!$groupWithSameName){`