# Slim Php Mysql Put method empty value,want to update 4 column,but only 1 column is updated but result indicate success

Tags: php, mysql, slim

My goal is to update 4 column in my table in a single query.But end up only 1 column is updated,the other 3 is not.

My query is like this

```
$stmt = $this->conn->prepare("UPDATE users_info SET profile_image_path = ?,user_bio = ? ,gender = ?,date_of_birth = ? WHERE user_id = ?");
$stmt->bind_param("sssii",$profile_image_upload_url,$user_bio,$gender,$date_of_birth,$user_id);
$result = $stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
return $result;
```

Here is my code for the query call

```
//update to database
global $user_id;
$db = new DBhandler();
$update_result = $db->callForQueryFunction($user_id,$user_bio,$date_of_birth,$gender,$profile_image_string);
$response = array();

if($update_result){
    $response['error'] = false;
    $response['message'] ="sucess";
}else{
    $response['error'] = true;
    $response['message'] ="fail";
}
```

After I run in advanced rest client ,with the the following query

> user_bio=hihi&gender=f&profile_image_string=somestringhere&date_of_birth=2015-08-16

After run the query,the result is always "success",but in Mysql table only `profile_image_path` column is updated,the rest 3 column `user_bio`,`date_of_birth` and `gender` all are not updated.

Here is my database structure 
[image: database structure]

I work for hours still haven't figure it out what's wrong with the code or my database structure.

**Update:**
I tried with `bind_param` for `s` with `$date_of_birth`,but still no luck with it

```
$stmt->bind_param("ssssi",$profile_image_upload_url,$user_bio,$gender,$date_of_birth,$user_id);
```

**UPDATE**
I actually using this example from [Androidhive](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/01/how-to-create-rest-api-for-android-app-using-php-slim-and-mysql-day-23/),the sample code is as below

```
       /**
     * Updating existing task
     * method PUT
     * params task, status
     * url - /tasks/:id
     */

$app->put('/tasks/:id', 'authenticate', function($task_id) use($app) {
            // check for required params
            verifyRequiredParams(array('task', 'status'));

            global $user_id;            
            $task = $app->request->put('task');
            $status = $app->request->put('status');
```

But I use the same method as below to grab the value,but after var_dump() all the value is `NULL`.Here is my code

```
$app->put('/updateuserdetails','authenticate',function ()use ($app){

$user_bio  = $app->request()->put('userbio');
$gender    =$app->request()->put('gender');
$date_of_birth = $app->request()->put('dob');
$profile_image_string = $app->request()->put('profilestring');
```

I try this as well.The value of `user_bio`,`gender`,`date_of_birth` are all still `null`.

```
$app->post('/updateuserdetails','authenticate',function ()use ($app){

$user_bio  = $app->request()->post('userbio');
$gender    =$app->request()->post('gender');
$date_of_birth = $app->request()->post('dob');
$profile_image_string = $app->request()->post('profilestring');
```

I just cant figure out what is going wrong here

**Update**
After I test it in Postman by send data with **x-www-form-urlencoded** it come out with this error,which I cant get any solution

[image: slim error]

Comment: for date_of_birth use `s` its of type date which will be string not inetger.  $stmt->bind_param("ssssi",$profile_image_upload_url,$user_bio,$gender,$date_of_birth,$user_id);

Comment: @Naincy I try this before,but the column still havent update.

Comment: Use var dump to ensure your variables have the value that you think they do: 
```var_dump($user_bio);```
```var_dump($gender);```
```var_dump($date_of_birth);```
```var_dump($user_id);```

Comment: by the way, why did you tag your question with pdo?

Comment: @YourCommonSense I tot is about pdo?sorry

Comment: @GreensterRox sir `$var_dump` and then get the value at where?I use Advance Rest Client

Comment: @GreensterRox wow..You help me noted that the 3 value is also null.thanks

Comment: @ken Figured as much :-)

Comment: @GreensterRox I using `put` method,why is it become null??

Comment: @Ken maybe post the code that shows how you are assigning these variables?? Are you using globals? e.g. $_POST ? I don't think that 'HTTP PUT' content is available using $_POST or $_REQUEST for example.

Comment: @GreensterRox actually I using Slim Framework.With update to server it use `Put` method.Wait I edit the question

Comment: @GreensterRox I update the question,feel free to take a look

Comment: @Ken are you using Postman to simulate the request?

Comment: @GreensterRox ya...postman

Comment: @Ken Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23761425/get-put-params-with-slim-php

Comment: @GreensterRox i try as well..but it have  `Uncaught exception 'InvalidArgumentException'` error.Sir,I updated the question

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
$stmt = $this->conn->prepare("UPDATE users_info SET profile_image_path = :image, user_bio = :bio, gender = :gender, date_of_birth = :dob WHERE user_id = :id");

$stmt->bindParam(":image", $profile_image_upload_url, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(":bio", $user_bio, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(":gender", $gender, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(":dob", $date_of_birth, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(":id", $user_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);

$result = $stmt->execute();

$stmt->close();

return $result;
```

Comment: dob should be PARAM_STR

Comment: @Naincy - just noticed the mistake. Has been corrected.