# PHP PUT method Slim framework

Tags: php, api, slim

May I ask why the put contains only an empty field? While the post is working normally?

```
$app->post('/books', function (Request $request, Response $response, $args){
    $book = Books::fromResultSet($request->getParsedBody());
    if($book->valid())
        return $response->withStatus(400);

    $book->insert();
    return $response->withStatus(201);
})->add($securityMiddleware);

$app->put('/books/{id}', function (Request $request, Response $response, $args){
    $book = Books::fromResultSet($request->getParsedBody());
    print_r($book);

    /*if($book->valid())
        return $response->withStatus(400);

    $book->update();
    return $response->withStatus(201);*/
})->add($securityMiddleware);
```

[image]

Errors after listing print_r ($ request-> getParsedBody ())

```
C:\MAMP\htdocs\vendor\slim\slim\Slim\Handlers\Strategies\RequestResponse.php(43): {closure}(Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\ServerRequest), Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response), Array)
    #1 C:\MAMP\htdocs\vendor\slim\slim\Slim\Routing\Route.php(384): Slim\Handlers\Strategies\RequestResponse-&gt;__invoke(Object(Closure), Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\ServerRequest), Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response), Array)
    #2 C:\MAMP\htdocs\public\index.php(27): Slim\Routing\Route-&gt;handle(Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\ServerRequest))
    #3 C:\MAMP\htdocs\vendor\slim\slim\Slim\MiddlewareDispatcher.php(313): {closure}(Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\ServerRequest), Object(Slim\Routing\Route))
    #4 C:\MAMP\htdocs\vendor\slim\slim\Slim\MiddlewareDispatcher.php(81): class@anonymous-&gt;handle(Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\ServerRequest))
    #5 C:\MAMP\htdocs\vendor\slim\slim\Slim\MiddlewareDispatcher.php(81): Slim\MiddlewareDispatcher-&gt;handle(Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\ServerRequest))
    #6 C:\MAMP\htdocs\vendor\slim\slim\Slim\Routing\Route.php(341): Slim\MiddlewareDispatcher-&gt;handle(Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\ServerRequest))
    #7 C:\MAMP\htdocs\vendor\slim\slim\Slim\Routing\RouteRunner.php(84): Slim\Routing\Route-&gt;run(Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\ServerRequest))
    #8 C:\MAMP\htdocs\vendor\slim\slim\Slim\Middleware\RoutingMiddleware.php(59): Slim\Routing\RouteRunner-&gt;handle(Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\ServerRequest))
    #9 C:\MAMP\htdocs\vendor\slim\slim\Slim\MiddlewareDispatcher.php(147): Slim\Middleware\RoutingMiddleware-&gt;process(Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\ServerRequest), Object(Slim\Routing\RouteRunner))
    #10 C:\MAMP\htdocs\vendor\slim\slim\Slim\Middleware\ErrorMiddleware.php(107): class@anonymous-&gt;handle(Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\ServerRequest))
    #11 C:\MAMP\htdocs\vendor\slim\slim\Slim\MiddlewareDispatcher.php(147): Slim\Middleware\ErrorMiddleware-&gt;process(Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\ServerRequest), Object(class@anonymous))
    #12 C:\MAMP\htdocs\vendor\slim\slim\Slim\MiddlewareDispatcher.php(81): class@anonymous-&gt;handle(Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\ServerRequest))
    #13 C:\MAMP\htdocs\vendor\slim\slim\Slim\App.php(215): Slim\MiddlewareDispatcher-&gt;handle(Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\ServerRequest))
    #14 C:\MAMP\htdocs\vendor\slim\slim\Slim\App.php(199): Slim\App-&gt;handle(Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\ServerRequest))
    #15 C:\MAMP\htdocs\public\index.php(85): Slim\App-&gt;run()
```

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23761425/get-put-params-with-slim-php answer that?

Comment: switching to: "x-www-form-urlencoded" doesn't help me

Comment: Hi, can you print the result of $request->getParsedBody()? Its any value return from the request?

Comment: you can se it on the picture

Comment: The picture is clearly the result of `print_r($book);` The suggestion was to post the result of `print_r($request->getParsedBody());` since we have no idea what `Books::fromResultSet(...)` does. However, I suspect the problem is in the code you haven't shown us - presumably it needs to look up the right book somewhere? It's also much more helpful to post text as text, not a picture of the text that we have to squint at.

Comment: you're right, I added it

Comment: @Aaron7 You said error after `getParsedBody()` but you only show the trace of error without its error message.

Comment: Make sure that postman sends `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` as content-type in the request header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer from [document](https://www.slimframework.com/docs/v4/middleware/body-parsing.html).

> It’s very common in web APIs to send data in JSON or XML format. Out of the box, PSR-7 implementations do not support these formats, you have to decode the Request object’s getBody() yourself. As this is a common requirement, Slim 4 provides BodyParsingMiddleware to handle this task.

After your `$app = AppFactory::create();`, add this code.

```php
// Parse json, form data and xml
$app->addBodyParsingMiddleware();
```

And inside your app function. Use `$request->getParsedBody()` as normal.
Example:

```php
$app->any('/books/{id}', function (Request $request, Response $response, $args){
    print_r($request->getParsedBody());
    return $response;
});
```

Result:
[image: Slim method PUT result]

If this still errors, please try to update Slim 4 to latest version and try again.